# ion auth codeigniter on php 7 not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, ion-auth

I creating a library called 'Basic' and in the library i call 'ion auth' library to checking user login. 
It's working on php 5, but when application running on php 7 users cannot login to app. I was checking the session data is empty on php 7. what's wrong ?

My 'Basic.php' library :

```
public function check_login(){
    //ajax request
    if ($this->_ci->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        if (!$this->_ci->ion_auth->logged_in())
        {
            if($this->is_pjax()){
                die('<script>alert("Anda belum login atau sesi login anda sudah habis, silahkan melakukan login ulang.");window.location.replace("'.base_url().'");</script>');
            }else{
                die(json_encode(array('status'=>false,'noty'=>'Anda belum login atau sesi login anda sudah habis, silahkan melakukan login ulang.')));
            }

        }else{
            $user_data=$this->_ci->ion_auth->user()->row();
            $user_data->grup=$this->_ci->ion_auth->get_users_groups()->row()->name;
            return $user_data;
        }
    }else{
        if (!$this->_ci->ion_auth->logged_in())
        {
            // redirect them to the login page
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {   
            $user_data=$this->_ci->ion_auth->user()->row();
            $user_data->grup=$this->_ci->ion_auth->get_users_groups()->row()->name;
            return $user_data;
        }
    }
}
```

My 'Auth' Controller to handle login :

```
    public function login()
{

    if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        $this->index();
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', str_replace(':', '', $this->lang->line('login_identity_email')), 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', str_replace(':', '', $this->lang->line('login_password_label')), 'required');


    //ajax request
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {


        if(!$this->basic->is_pjax()){

            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

            $res=array('status'=>false,'noty'=>'Login Gagal !');
            //sleep(10);
            $post=$this->input->post(null,true);

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
            {
                if ($this->ion_auth->login($post['email'], $post['password'], false))
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
                    $res=array('status'=>true,'noty'=>'Login Berhasil !');
                }
            }else{
                $res['noty']=(validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');
            }

            die(json_encode($res));
        }else{

            $this->data['title'] = $this->lang->line('login_heading');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
            {
                // check to see if the user is logging in
                // check for "remember me"
                $remember = (bool) $this->input->post('remember');

                if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember))
                {
                    $user_data=$this->ion_auth->user()->row();

                    $grupname=$this->ion_auth->get_users_groups($user_data->id)->row()->name;



                    //if the login is successful
                    //redirect them back to the home page
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
                    if (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin()) // remove this elseif if you want to enable this for non-admins
                    {
                        // redirect them to the home page because they must be an administrator to view this
                        //redirect('/', 'refresh');
                        die('<script>window.location.replace("'.base_url().'dashboard");</script>');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        die('<script>window.location.replace("'.base_url().'admin/dashboard");</script>');
                        //redirect('admin/dashboard', 'refresh');
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    // if the login was un-successful
                    // redirect them back to the login page
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
                    $this->login_view();
                    ///redirect('login', 'refresh'); // use redirects instead of loading views for compatibility with MY_Controller libraries
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // the user is not logging in so display the login page
                // set the flash data error message if there is one
                $this->login_view();

            }
        }
    }else{
        $this->login_view();
    }
}
```

And on every controllers i added this code to checking user login:

```
$this->data['user_data']=$this->basic->check_login();
```

Comment: I have used ion_auth on sites with php v7.0 7.1 & 7.2 without any issues.

Comment: Me as well. Currently am. Not an issue with Ion Auth. Go through the typical debugging routes.

Comment: how to debugging routes @Alex ?

Comment: Echos vardumps and prints rs to make sure your inputs and outputs are what you expect.

Comment: Start in the Ion Auth model where it adds the session vars. Do a echo something there to see if it's reached, if not, work your way backwards to see what condition is failing. Turn on error reporting, are you getting any errors? If not that's strange as a php difference (if that were the issue) would certainly cause errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have same issues with this library:
* Name:  Ion Auth
* Version: 2.5.2
* Author: Ben Edmunds
with PHP 7

Basicaly i found problem in last parameter of function: login.

if remember parameter is set to 0 don't work if set to 1 it workS!

so in your code try this:

change

```
if ($this->ion_auth->login($post['email'], $post['password'], false))
```

with

```
if ($this->ion_auth->login($post['email'], $post['password'], true))
```

Comment: this solved my problem with my old CI app that supposed to be running on PHP5 but hosting forced to 7.2. many thanks.